# dojo - declare function

Tags: javascript, dojo

I can't seem to get the dojo example about declare to work. Example link : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/declare.html#id3

Here is how I set it up:

/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
    <script src="/my/Employee.js"></script>
    <script src="/my/Person.js"></script>
    <script>
        var dojoConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: true,
            packages: [{
                "name": "my",
                "location": location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/my"
            }
            ]
        };
    </script>

    <script>
        require(["my/Person"], function (Person)
        {
            var folk = new Person("phiggins", 42, "Tennessee");
        });

        require(['my/Employee'], function (Employee)
        {
            var matt = new Employee("Matt", 33, "California", 1000);

            console.log(kathryn.askForRaise(), matt.askForRaise()); // 3600, 20
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

/my/Person.js

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function (declare)
{
    return declare(null, {
        constructor: function (name, age, residence)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.residence = residence;
        }
    });
});
```

/my/Employee.js

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "my/Person"], function (declare, Person)
{
    return declare(Person, {
        constructor: function (name, age, residence, salary)
        {
            // The "constructor" method is special: the parent class (Person)
            // constructor is called automatically before this one.

            this.salary = salary;
        },

        askForRaise: function ()
        {
            return this.salary * 0.02;
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to set a break point in all the call back method (return declare ...) and it never gets in there. It never gets into the require block's callback also.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Dojo... what a great framework that very few use... unfair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just a couple of small issues with your HTML file.

In your script tag that loads Dojo, you have added the `data-dojo-config` attribute. This is one of two ways to tell Dojo how it should behave - the other way is to define a global `dojoConfig` object. You've done both! So, remove the `data-dojo-config` attribute.

Now, Dojo needs to know about the config object just when it loads. So the `dojoConfig` has to be defined before the script tag that loads Dojo. Since `async:true` was just removed, add it to the config object instead.

Also, as Buffalo has mentioned, there's no need to include the Person and Employee modules with script tags. Dojo uses a pattern called AMD (Async Module Definitions) for loading modules. Basically that's the `define` and `require` functions you see here and there. These load the modules by very conveniently inserting the script tags for you (as long as you've told them where to find your namespace in the `dojoConfig`).

So the beginning of your head should be something like this:

```
<script>
    var dojoConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: true,
        async: true,
        packages: [{
            "name": "my",
            "location": location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/my"
        }]
    };
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

That's actually all you need to make Dojo load your classes as it should. However, I think there's another small gotcha you may want to be aware of:

First, you require the Person module. Dojo will do its module loading magic behind the scenes and call `function(Person) {...}` when it's done. Next, you do the same with the Employee module and call `function(Employee) {... }`. You should keep in mind that you cannot guarantee that `function(Person)` is called before `function(Employee)`. If, for example, you loaded Person and 100 other modules, `function(Employee)` would be called first.

(I mention this because I suspected that kathryn was a typo, and that you intended you use the folk object instead. I see now that that probably wasn't the case, but I'll leave it here anyway).

Answer (score 1):

At least one change you'll want to make is to remove the lines

```
<script src="/my/Employee.js"></script>
<script src="/my/Person.js"></script>
```

One of the main selling points AMD modules is that you can have reusable modules without needing to add script tags everywhere in your html files.

Another debugging tip would be to check the inspector for any console errors or network errors.